# Prove that $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ is not periodic, without using derivation

Tags: periodic-functions

So basically I'm supposed to prove that identity, without using derivations. I've seen this question posted here already, and one answer offered derivations, another said, what I basically tried to do before coming here, to assume f(x) = f(x+T) and solve for T, but I'm not sure how to proceed on $\sin(\sqrt{x})=\sin(\sqrt{x+T})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

You have to solve for $T$ the equation 
$$
\sin \sqrt{x}=\sin(\sqrt{x+T})
$$
and find a solution that is a constant (i.e. independent from $x$).  But we have:

$$
\sqrt{x} +2k\pi=\sqrt{x+T} \iff x+4k^2\pi^2+4k\pi\sqrt{x}=x+T
$$
so T cannot be a constant

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is the period,

$$\sin\sqrt T=\sin0.$$

But then $$\sin\sqrt{2T}=0$$ can't be true. (Solve for $T$ to check.)

Answer (score 1):

**just a Hint**

Assume

$\forall x\geq 0$

$\sin(\sqrt{x+T})=\sin(\sqrt x)$

$\implies$

$\sqrt{x+T}=\sqrt{x}+2k\pi$

and by squaring

$T=4k^2\pi^2+4k\pi\sqrt{x}$

thus if $x=0$, it gives $T=4\pi^2$

and if $x=\frac{1}{16}$, we get

$T=4\pi^2+\pi$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

1. $f(x)=\sin\sqrt x$ is not defined for $x\lt0$, hence cannot satisfy an equation of the form $f(x)=f(x+T)$ for all $x$.
2. The zeroes of $f(x)=\sin\sqrt x$ are $x=n^2\pi^2$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$.  The spacing between consecutive zeroes is $(2n+1)\pi^2$, which eventually exceeds any possible period $T\gt0$.

Remark:  The first reason might be dismissed if your definition of periodicity as $f(x)=f(x+T)$ for some $T\gt0$ is restricted to  $x$ (and $x+T$) *in the domain* of $f$, or if you use periodicity to *extend* the domain of $f$ to values of $x$ where it's not defined.