# Proof that $ \sin \sqrt{x}$ is not periodic function using contradiction method?

Tags: periodic-functions

Proof that $ \sin \sqrt{x}$ is not periodic function using contradiction method ?

**My approach**
For periodic $$f(x+T)=f(x)$$
Let $x=0$
$$\sin \sqrt{(T+0)}=\sin\sqrt{0}$$
$$\sqrt{ T} =n\pi$$
Let $x= T$
$$\sin \sqrt{2T}=\sin\sqrt{T}$$

After this I can't able to solve

Comment: Did you mean $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ ?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2020495/42969.

Comment: Actually your method is good, from your last equation, you get $\sin(\sqrt{2}n\pi)=0$. This cannot happen, unless $n=0$ but in this case $T=0$. A contradiction, since a period should be different from $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$